# Flatten and create new columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table:

```
UserID Course
1      ENGLISH
1      MATH  
2      ENGLISH
2      PHILOSOPHY
3      MATH
```

I would like to have the following table:

```
UserID Course1  Course2     Course3
1      ENGLISH  MATH 
2      ENGLISH  PHILOSOPHY
3      MATH
```

How should I do that with Pandas?

Note that I have lots of thousands of courses, so create one column for each course would not make sense.

Comment: Your method that you have tried and shown here will not work.

Comment: If you can't create a column for each course, then maybe you want `user#1: courses: [ENGLISH,MATH]`. Though, the obvious problem with this is that you can't check if a user is enrolled in a specific course without traversing the list.

Comment: @keyser I don't want to create array columns because I want to fit my table to a statistical model. sshashank: I haven't figured out conceptually how I should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a column containing the 'Course number' (per user) and then pivot it.

```
df['CourseNr'] = df.groupby('UserID').cumcount().apply(lambda x: 'Course%i' % (x+1))
```

Gives:

```
   UserID      Course  CourseNr
0       1     ENGLISH  Course1
1       1        MATH  Course2
2       2     ENGLISH  Course1
3       2  PHILOSOPHY  Course2
4       3        MATH  Course1
```

Then:

```
pd.pivot(df.UserID, df.CourseNr, df.Course)
```

Results in:

```
CourseNr Course1      Course2
UserID                       
1         ENGLISH        MATH
2         ENGLISH  PHILOSOPHY
3            MATH         NaN
```